# What are the differences between javascript export syntaxes?

Tags: javascript, syntax, es6-modules

I'm trying to understand if there are any differences between the ways to export a component in javascript. I understand how a default export works, and how to export variables, like:

```js
// when exporting a function:
export function foo () {}
// you can import it as
import {foo} from "foo";

// default export
export default class foo {}
//then:
import foo from "foo";
```

But I've seen cases like:

```js
export {foo as default} from "foo";
export {foo as default, bar} from "foo";
export {default} from "foo";
export {default as foo} from "foo";
```

Could someone explain what the `default` keyword means in the 4 cases above and how can I import it?

Comment: Those are re-exports, so a combination of import and export statements.

Answer (score 1):

```
// import foo and export it as default
export {foo as default} from "foo"; 

// import foo and export it as default
// import bar and immediately export bar
export {foo as default, bar} from "foo";

// import default as foo and export it
export {default as foo} from "foo"; 

// re-exporting the default export 
export {default} from "foo";
```

All these are Re-exports, means to import things and immediately export them.

Comment: We can have one `export default` per file, right? So, why we can have multiple `export {foo as default} from... ` `export {bar as default} from...` in a single file?

Comment: Yes, only one default export is allowed per module. So, this `export {foo as default} from... export {bar as default}` will not work. You can re-export all like `export {bar} from ....` and can have **only one default export** like `export {foo as default} ...`

Comment: But I think it works, at least I've seen this in a lot of places, like [here](https://github.com/MuhammadSuhail/ReactConverterCurrency/blob/4a763fcab745df5976e7c3985b2ef0d74b83692b/jspm_packages/npm/lodash-es%404.17.4/lodash.js)

Comment: That's different. `export { default as add } from './add.js';` - here you are re-exporting the default export of add.js file as **add**